# How do I use visual studio designer with xna game project? Is this a possible thing?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xna

I am new to xna!! I never used xna before.  The Designer makes it easier to design where you want everything. I am just making a simple 2D Puzzle game for the PC, however I want to use an xbox controller to move the cursor and switch the blocks. I decided to try xna. I am new and lost. Can you help? I haven't started yet. I just opened it and wondering if I have to manually code all the images. or if I can just place them in a design view.

Comment: Where's your code?  Please see [Ask].

Comment: I don't have any code yet. all I did was start a new project. I have not even used XNA yet.

Answer (score 0):

At this point, you need to look into [MonoGame](http://www.monogame.net/), it implements the Microsoft XNA programming interface.

XNA was for PC, Xbox 360, Windows Phone 7 and Zune.

XNA does not have a visual editor, however [Unreal 4](https://www.unrealengine.com/what-is-unreal-engine-4) and [Unity](https://unity3d.com/) do. I suggest these because you said "XNA Designer".